# Issues with implementing the login using shared preference

Tags: android, authentication, logout

I have mentioned my complete code for the login and logout process to my application. Sometimes this code works but sometimes it just allows me to go to menu activity even without login. FYI: this code really worked earlier once i wanted to implement the remember me option, then only all these issues came up. can anyone check this and find me my issue or suggest me if u got any proper code for this process.  when i logout and and open the application sometimes i can see the menu.

I have used shared preference and not using sessions for login and logout. is it correct. Im bit confused i would really appreciate any help. thanx in advance.

login code

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog prgDialog;

    EditText emailET;
    EditText pwdET;
    String email;
    String password;
    Button button;
    public static String PREFS_NAME = "mypre";
    public static String PREF_EMAIL = "email";
    public static String PREF_PASSWORD = "password";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {

                    String email = emailET.getText().toString();
                    String password = pwdET.getText().toString();

                    if (Utility.isNotNull(email) && Utility.isNotNull(password)) {

                        if (Utility.validate(email)) {

                            if (emailET.getText().toString().equals(email)
                                    && pwdET.getText().toString()
                                    .equals(password)) {
                                CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ch_rememberme);
                                if (ch.isChecked())
                                    rememberMe(email, password); 
                            }

                            new LoginAsyncTask(LoginActivity.this).execute(
                                    email, password);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Login process started...",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Login error, invalid email",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                          
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Login error, don't leave any field blank",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }

            }
        });

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_landing);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LandingActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LandingActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,
                    R.anim.slide_out_right);
            finish();
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // read email and password from SharedPreferences
        getUser();
    }

    public void getUser() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String email = pref.getString(PREF_EMAIL, null);
        String password = pref.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, null);

        if (email != null || password != null) {
            // directly show logout form
            showLogout(email);
        }
    }

    public void rememberMe(String user, String password) {
        // save email and password in SharedPreferences
        getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
        .putString(PREF_EMAIL, user).putString(PREF_PASSWORD, password)
        .commit();
    }

    public void showLogout(String email) {
        // display log out activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMenu.class);
        intent.putExtra("user", email);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,
                R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }

}
```

logout code

```
final RelativeLayout relativeLayout3 = (RelativeLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.logoutlistview);
        relativeLayout3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                        PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String email = pref.getString(PREF_EMAIL, null);
                String password = pref.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, null);
                if (email != null || password != null ) {

                    Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.commit();
                    email = "";
                    password = "";
                    firstname = "";
                    lastname = "";
                    // show login form
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            LActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    intent.addFlags(IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                else {

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It is better if you use the default authenticator  provided by android framework, Have a look at this http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-authenticator.html

Answer (score 0):

use this method to create a sharedPreference and then access it with this     same name from any where in any activity within the same app

```
SharedPreference sp;
sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(My_PREFERENCE,
            context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor e = sp.edit();
e.put(key,value);
 e.commit();
```

and when getting the same sharedPreference in another activity use this method

```
SharedPreference sp;
sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(My_PREFERENCE,
            context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.get(key,value);
```

Comment: what should use for the values key,value?

Comment: key : any name like constant name.value:whatever value you want save

Comment: is it like password,password) (email,email)?

Comment: like sp.put("PASSWORD",user entered password)

Comment: refer this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link which might help you.

http://androidapplicationdeveloper.weebly.com/login-and-logout-useing-sharedprefrences.html

**In your code you have didn't set values of sharedpreference to blank while logout.**

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Ok. Let me know if need my help.